# Screen Sizes for every tab in android

Tags: android-layout

I want to develop an application for all tabs available in android,for using pictures I have to resize them according to tabs screen sizes for providing multiple screen scenario.Can anyone tell me what sizes pictures for each layout folder I have to take for providing best user interface on each tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).

720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

Comment: OK,suppose I have a picture of 320*480 then what size I have to provide so that it will run normally on each android tab.

Comment: suppose 320*480 is your mdpi image. then you need to make hdpi,xhdpi and ldpi images size for the same according to mdpi size.

Comment: I assume you know the baseline ratio for the image. if you make mdpi asa base image then other image size will be say "ldpi 0.75x", "hdpi 1.5x", "xhdpi 2.0x"

Comment: So for that what is the ratio?Means how can I calculate it for hdpi,xhdpi and ldpi?

Comment: also you will get some helpful stuff from here : [Support Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)